# How to include an image in HTML without showing it on screen

Tags: html

I want to show an image on an HTML5 canvas without putting it on screen first. I've tried `<noscript>` but that doesn't work as then I can't include the image into my code.
Here's my HTML:

```
<html>
    <noscript>
        <img id = "tiles" src="img/tiles.png">
    </noscript>
    <title>Super Mario World</title>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
        <script src="sketch.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

Here's my javascript: 

var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var _img = document.getElementById('id1');
var newImg = new Image().src = _img;

context.drawImage(newImg,0,0);
```

Comment: Sorry I don't have time for a detailed answer, but two ways I can think of off my head: Use an image in your HTML, but hide it using CSS (display: none), or you could also request the image data via AJAX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    <img id = "tiles" src="img/tiles.png" style="display:none;">
```

then to display it

```
  document.getElementById("tiles").style.display = "block";
```

EDIT:

That was a quick answer to the question but, a far better approach would be to create a class

```
 .hidden {
   display : none;
 }
```

then add it to elements.

```
<img id = "tiles" src="img/tiles.png" class="hidden">
```

and remove it to display

```
 var element = document.getElementById("tiles");
 element.classList.remove("hidden");
```

The reasoning behind this is that if the original display wasn't block, this would create issues, also it is generally discouraged to use inline style.